# How to write typescript executable file?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Using `babel-cli` you could easily write some node-executable using es2015 syntax. For that you just need to add proper shebang `#!/usr/bin/env babel-node`.

For example,

```js
#!/usr/bin/env babel-node

import fs from 'fs';

fs.readFileSync('./some-file.csv');
```

I am wondering how to do that using TypeScript?

**UPDATE:** Tried `ts-node` - getting awkward errors even for HelloWorld examples like

```js
const say = (word: string) => {
    console.log(word);
}

say('hello');
```

it does not work via `ts-node test.ts` or using `#!/usr/bin/env ts-node`;

In both cases i'm getting

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin/ts-node.ts:110:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

**UPDATE** Made `ts-node` work. It works only if file has `.ts` extension. For files without extension but with shebang - it does not work. Created github [issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/116) for the project that reflects needed behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to note things have moved on since the approach tried by @ValeriiVasin and the one recommended in @Paarth's answer.

[Support for shebangs](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#shebang) was officially added in [ts-node v8.9.0](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/releases/tag/v8.9.0). The recommended shebang string now includes the `-script` suffix:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node-script
```

Scripts using `fs.readFileSync("somefile.json")` are working for me with this shebang.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node

...rest of script
```

Author confirms this usage working here:
https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/73

p.s. I'd call that an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), not a [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file).

Comment: I tried that yesterday, but apparently it does not work with non-helloworld examples...

Comment: If you import other modules and want to be able to call the script from outside the project directory, have a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61021655/12917821) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/995), which goes into more detail.