# Use an npm script as "bin"

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a command line application written in TypeScript with some npm scripts defined in `package.json`.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "start-args": "ts-node src/index.ts -- some args"
  },
```

I would like to link and alias the TypeScript file so that I can call the program easily, so I am looking for something like a `"bin"` key in the `package.json` file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
    "start-args": "ts-node src/index.ts -- some args"
  },
  "bin": {
    "foobar": "./src/index.ts",
    "bazqux": "./src/index.ts some args"
  }
```

`ts-node` is installed locally.

However, since TypeScript is not natively supported by node, just putting a shebang on `./src/index.ts` won't work.

I would also like to be able to create an aliased command with default arguments, like `bazqux` above. When I link or install the package as global, I can run "foobar" globally as if I run "npm run start" inside the repository; or run "bazqux" globally as it's "npm run start-args".

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: The issue described below has been fixed in [`ts-node@8.9.0`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/releases/tag/v8.9.0) thanks to my report. `--script-mode` now resolves symlinks before looking for the `tsconfig.json` file. The correct shebang to use is `#!/usr/bin/env ts-node-script`, which is now also [documented](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#shebang). Make sure you have the newest version installed globally with `npm -g install ts-node`. (I'm not sure whether you also/still need TypeScript installed globally for this. If yes: `npm -g install typescript`.)

**Outdated**: For those who also still stumble across this problem, I documented my current approach in detail in [this issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/995). In short, many modules (including those of Node.js itself) require that you use the [`--esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) option for the TypeScript compiler. (You can specify this in your `tsconfig.json` file.) In order to be able to use your command from anywhere and not just from within your package directory, you have to use the undocumented [`--script-mode`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/blob/92cf9613828c2ba2fe37b7a0aa7895e122c16185/src/bin.ts#L240-L258) option for [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) or the undocumented [`ts-node-script`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/blob/92cf9613828c2ba2fe37b7a0aa7895e122c16185/package.json#L10) command, which does [the same](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/blob/master/src/bin-script.ts).

In other words, your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) should either be `#!/usr/bin/env -S ts-node --script-mode` or `#!/usr/bin/env ts-node-script`. (The former uses [`-S`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#g_t_002dS_002f_002d_002dsplit_002dstring-usage-in-scripts) to pass arguments to the specified interpreter. If this doesn't work on your platform, you can try to [hack around](http://sambal.org/2014/02/passing-options-node-shebang-line/) this limitation.)

If you want to use the [`bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) functionality of `npm` (e.g. by running [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) from the package directory), the above doesn't work because `--script-mode` does not (yet?) follow symbolic links. To work around this, you can use `#!/usr/bin/env -S ts-node --project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/<your-project>/tsconfig.json` on the first line of your script. This is not ideal, though, as it breaks platform independence. The only other option I see at the moment is to use a bash script instead and call your script from there.

Answer (score 3):

It will work, if `ts-node` is in path variable use

```
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node
console.log("Hello World");
```

Checkout repo:
https://github.com/deepakshrma/ts-cli

Try out:

```
$ npm i -g https://git@github.com:deepakshrma/ts-cli.git
$ ts-test
```

Comment: This approach fails as soon as you have local dependencies in your project. See my answer for a more reliable solution.