# How to build a TypeScript shell command that installs portably and globally?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, yarnpkg, ts-node

I would like to build a command-line tool written in TypeScript that becomes available in the `$PATH` when installed. My requirements:

- I can run and test it from within the project folder (e.g., `yarn command`, `npm run command`)
- It should be installable via `npm install -g mycommand`
- When installed, it can be invoked like a regular shell command
- It doesn't require other NPM modules to be *explicitly* globally installed
- (*soft requirement*) I'd rather avoid having to use Webpack

A [common solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37273305/225386) is to use `ts-node` in the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env ts-node`) but that requires that `ts-node` is globally installed.

#### What I have so far...

My project structure:

```
├── cli.ts
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── util.ts
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "mycommand",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./bin/cli.js",
  "bin": {
    "mycommand": "./bin/cli.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "mycommand": "ts-node ./cli.ts",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cli-color": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/inquirer": "^8.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.29",
    "@types/shelljs": "^0.8.11",
    "@types/yargs": "^17.0.10",
    "cli-color": "^2.0.2",
    "inquirer": "^8.2.3",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "yargs": "^17.4.1"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "bin",
    "composite": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2017",
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  }
}
```

`cli.ts`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node

import * as yargs from "yargs";
import * from "./util";

yargs
    .command({
        // ...
    })
    .help()
    .vargs
```

This allows me to run the script locally using `yarn mycommand` and to install it via `yarn install -g` but the shell complains that `ts-node` is not found (since the shebang line.

Answer (score 0):

Three modifications that need to be made:

1. The `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` need to output the correct module type supported by the version of Node:

   ```json
     ...
     "lib": [
       "es2021"
     ],
     "module": "UMD",
     "target": "es2021",
     ...
   ```

   The TSConfig project has [recommended bases for various environments](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases). The above snippet is based on the recommendation for Node 16+, which my project targets.
2. The shebang line should use `node`, not `ts-node`. Running it locally through a Yarn/NPM script overrides it anyway:

   ```sh
   #!/usr/bin/env node
   ```
3. Add a `preinstall` script to transpile the TypeScript file into JavaScript:

   ```json
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "preinstall": "yarn build",
     ...
   ```